# Override existing Docs in production MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, production-environment, upsert

I have recently changed one of my fields from `object` to `array of objects`.

In my production I have only 14 documents with this field, so I decided to change those fields.

Is there any best practices to do that?

As it is in my production I need to do it in a best way possible?

I got the document Id's of those collections.like `['xxx','yyy','zzz',...........]`

my doc structure is like

```
_id:"xxx",option1:{"op1":"value1","op2":"value2"},option2:"some value"
```

and I want to change it like(converting object to array of objects)

```
_id:"xxx",option1:[{"op1":"value1","op2":"value2"},
                   {"op1":"value1","op2":"value2"}
                 ],option2:"some value"
```

Can I use `upsert`? If so How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to create the new value of the field based on the old value, you should retrieve each document with a query like

```
db.collection.find({ "_id" : { "in" : [<array of _id's>] } })
```

then iterate over the results and `$set` the value of the field to its new value:

```
db.collection.find({ "_id" : { "in" : [<array of _id's>] } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    oldVal = doc.option1
    newVal = compute_newVal_from_oldVal(oldVal)
    db.collection.update({ "_id" : doc._id }, { "$set" : { "option" : newVal } })
})
```

The document structure is rather schematic, so I omitted putting in actual code to create `newVal` from `oldVal`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an embedded document type you could use push query

```
db.collectionname.update({_id:"xxx"},{$push:{option1:{"op1":"value1","op2":"value2"}}})
```

This will create document inside embedded document.Hope it helps